# Adding to an object

Tags: javascript, object, twitter

I have a function that returns data from the twitter API, what I want to know is how do I push the data and form an object that looks like this:

```
var obj = {

'some_user_name': ['stirng of their tweets']

}
```

I know for an array you can simply `.push()` the data but what is the corresponding command for objects?

Comment: `obj.yourVariable = dataYouget` you add to objects using dot notation

Answer (score 1):

ES6

```
function pushToObject(obj, key, ...items) {
   if (!Array.isArray(obj[key])) obj[key] = [];
   return obj[key].push(...items);
}
```

usage

```
var o = {};

pushToObject(o, 'foo', 'fizz', 'buzz'); // 2
pushToObject(o, 'foo', 'hello', 'world'); // 4

o; // {"foo": ["fizz", "buzz", "hello", "world"]}
```